# OS Distro benchmarks website?

Tags: linux, benchmark, bsd, distribution

Im looking for website which contains OS distro benchmarks (comparing in 32 & 64 bit, comparing PHP execution on the distro, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Phoronix is really good about os benchamrks:
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=category&item=Operating%20Systems